# In a git repository is it possible to pre-specify "remotes" in the clone's configs?

Tags: git

In a git repository I would like to "pre specify" remotes so when one clones the repository the remotes are pre-loaded into the clone's `.git/config`? Is this reasonably possible ? If so how?

Comment: As far as I know it is not. But, could you explain a little bit more the reason you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not permit you to influence the configuration of a repository like that.

A common solution is to distribute a script with your repository that will perform the necessary repository configuration: setting up remotes, hooks, etc.  You can then instruct people to run the script if they want that particular configuration.

Comment: Alas what I thought. :|

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no, but see step 4 below.

The `git clone` command is, modulo a few special corner issues, equivalent to:

1. `mkdir target`, where *target* is derived from the URL you're cloning (and skipped if you give `git clone` the name of an existing empty directory).  Subsequent operations are run inside the target directory.
2. `git init`
3. `git remote add remote url`.  The *`remote`* here defaults to `origin` but you can specify some other name.
4. Additional `git config` commands, if specified on the command line (`-c` or `--config`).
5. `git fetch remote`.
6. `git checkout branch`, where *`branch`* is the one you specified on the command line, or the one directed by the Git from which step 4 fetched.

The built in remote, `origin` by default, is configured via the equivalent of `git remote add`, but that does the equivalent of:

```
git config remote.<remote>.url <url>
git config remote.<remote>.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<remote>/*'
```

(where the angle-bracket items are replaced in the obvious way).

This means that if you can convince people to run:

```
git clone \
    -c remote.abc.url=ssh://example.com/path/to/abc.git \
    -c remote.abc.fetch='+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/abc/*' \
    ssh://example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

(instead of just `git clone ssh://example.com/path/to/repo.git`), *then* they will have a configured `abc` remote.  But that's up to the people running `git clone`: your `repo.git` cannot affect their `.git/config` directly this same way.